# WKWebView shows white screen for a long time after start request

Tags: ios, networking, wkwebview

I'm using `WKWebView` to load a local html file using

```
[self.webView loadFileURL:tmpUrl allowingReadAccessToURL:directoryUrl];
```

Currently the webView will keep white screen for a long time, and once it shows content, all images were already downloaded.

It looks like the `WKWebView` will only render after all images downloaded.

Sample HTML content is here: https://pastebin.com/681btcSa

---

Then I did some test for pages without images. It seems that when loading complex HTML, WKWebView always takes a long time before render anything on screen.

I tried to call `_updateVisibleContentRects` and `setNeedsLayout`, but it helps little.

Comment: Provide the HTML file to identify the issue

Comment: @Subramanian I've attached sample html content in pastebin

Comment: My workaround was adding a delay when presenting the view (changing the web view alpha from 0 to 1) on `webView:didFinishNavigation:`. Ugly solution though.

Comment: try to set the backgroundColor of your WebView to black and opaque to false.